# Converting CURL request to HTTP Request Java by method GET

Tags: java, curl, get

I have the following CURL request Can anyone please confirm me what would be the subsequent HTTP Request:

```
curl -i -L -H "Accept: application/json" --data "client_id=APP-UJA2FDFLIVK14WMW&client_secret=6d8d32f1-1c25-4356-8b15-4d803d9a869e&grant_type=authorization_code&code=dj4kYk&redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground" "https://api.sandbox.orcid.org/oauth/token"
```

Can anyone be kind enough to help me convert the above curl request completely to httpreq.

Comment: you should really give it a try first and if you get stuck, post your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at this post: [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

You should be able to pass the data part as is:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + dataString).openConnection();
```

using:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept: application/json", charset);
```

to add the header

This is a starting point...